# Eclipse 2021-03: JavaScript formatter settings not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I can't get any JavaScript formatter settings to work (e.g. setting the tab policy to "Spaces only").

- Fresh download of 2021-03 "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers" for Windows
- New workspace
- New "Static Web Project"
- Changed the JavaScript formatter in both the global eclipse settings as well as the project specific settings
- Default include path
- Editing with "Generic Text Editor"
- Ctrl + Shift + F does format the file, but always with some default settings (with tabs)

[image]

[image]

Comment: For JavaScript support there are two alternatives, _Generic Text Editor_ means via language sever by [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) and _JavaScript_ editor by [Eclipse WTP JSDT](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) to which the shown preferences belong.

Comment: @howlger ok thanks for the hint. I don't see "JavaScript editor" in the "Editor Selection"-Dialog. And I suspect I want the editor from the Wild Web Developer, as this is the new web tooling, no?

Comment: @howlger do you know how to change the formatter settings of the language server?

Comment: It depends, WWD is newer, but JSDT still alive. JSDT is implemented in Java; WWD uses the language server from VS Code, but for formatting settings, etc. there is no UI. See https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/225#issuecomment-523807311

Comment: Thanks for those issue links. Care to convert to an answer?

Comment: Are you *sure* that's 2021-03?

Comment: @nitind yes, why?

Comment: My own confusion, never mind about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JavaScript support there are two alternatives,

- ***Generic Text Editor*** by [**Eclipse Wild Web Developer**](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) uses a newer approach by embedding and using the JavaScript/TypeScript language sever from Visual Studio Code
- ***JavaScript Editor*** by [**Eclipse WTP JSDT**](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) which is missing in the *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers*, but is the one to which the **shown preferences belong**; in contrast, it is completely implemented in Java, exists longer and is still alive

To configure the formatter used in the *Generic Text Editor*, see [Angelo Zerr comment](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/225#issuecomment-523807311):

> According [this comment](https://github.com/theia-ide/typescript-language-server/issues/10#issuecomment-333516152), try to
>
> - create in your project root a `tsfmt.json`
> - fill this JSON file like https://github.com/vvakame/typescript-formatter#read-settings-from-files